# How can i hardcode an SQLite Database for an Android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I' m developing an Android app wich requires me to use a Database.
After reading a while, i' ve decided to use an SQLite database, i started reading how do i should work with it, but every book/tutorial/etc... develop an Updatable database by allowing the user to add information to it. (like a diary or a running time record app style).
I just need to create (i mean, like hardcoding) my database and query it. My database will not be updatable by user side. 
I' m pretty sure it should be an easy/dummy way to do it but i'm not finding it yet.
So, if anyone can help me, it would be awesome. ;)

Thanks.
Amet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following link:
[SQLite database tutorial with DAO and Content Provider](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

You need only 2 classes:

- The database class (4.3. Database and Data Model):

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
        + " text not null);";

    // Database creation sql statement
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE tablename....."

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // You don't need this. If you don't change the DATABASE_VERSION value then this method will not be called.
}
```

}

- DAO

public class CommentsDataSource {

```
// Database fields
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
        MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT };

public CommentsDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
        comments.add(comment);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return comments;
}

private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
    return comment;
}
```

}

- BUT I suggest you to check the Content provider example as well (8.4. Create ContentProvider).  It is not complicated at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQLiteOpenHelper's onCreate method to execute the sql needed to create your database. The sql could either be hard coded or read in from a file. Doing it this way would allow you initialize the database when the application is first ran.

Another option would be to use a tool such as [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)

This is a desktop application that you can use to build the sqlite database. Once you've created it you'll have to decide how to deploy it. I've never tried doing this but I imagine you could bundle it in your resource folder and then move it into the correct directory when the app first runs after being installed.